# Is it possible to link css transitions to scrollTop value?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, position, transition

I'm working on a website with parallax and some scrolling effects, you can find it here:

http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i283196/qoala/

As you can see there are some elements that react to the scroll position. I achieved this with  jQuery. A friend of mine pointed out that it didn't work so smooth on windows/IE (I use a mac) and he suggested I used CSS Transitions instead.

I tried this out, but now (in a different version than the link), the expanding of the menubar for instance, is triggered, but the animation just completes when it hits the trigger. This isn't what I want. I want the animation to be 'linked' to the users scrolling.

My question is; Is this possible with CSS Transitions or should I stick to jQuery? And if i have to stick to jQuery, is there a solution for the spotty animations?

Thanks very much in advance!

Comment: Please DO NOT link to your web site. Here's why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Answer (score 1):

The problem with "CSS Transitions" on your specific case, is the fact that you want it linked to the `scroll` event. To do so, you will be relying on Js/jQuery anyways to call the right "transition" in effect replicating tools already existent out there.

My advise is to use a more responsive **jQuery** plugin for animations that offload the work using "CSS Transitions".

**Even Better:** Use the [`velocity.js`](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) library.